# R shiny mouseover to all table cells

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, dt

How I can achieve mouse hover text for all table cells (not for column names).I am having the datatable with 3 columns. On hover over the cell of 3rd column, need to display the combined contents of 1st and 2nd columns of that particiular row.I tried exploring DT package to achieve the same but no success.Any tips or do we have any library which supports hover for tables.

Comment: This would give you some ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970097/tooltip-or-popover-in-shiny-datatables-for-row-names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `rowCallback` to do this. Here is a simple example for what you want to achieve:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
    ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$mtcarsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars[,1:3], 
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                      "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                      "var full_text = aData[0] + ','+ aData[1] + ',' + aData[2] + ','+ aData[3];",
                      "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
                                            "}")
                    )
      )

    })
  }
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @SBista. I am able to achieve this few days back with similar approach.Need a quick solution, I also need to change _mouse cursor_ to **pointer** when user hover over 3rd column row cells. Any tips.

Comment: Able to achieve this using CSS - **"$('td:eq(5)', nRow).css('cursor', 'pointer');",**

Comment: @SBista: Is there a way to do this for every single column? Same message? Eg I wanted to do this for the entire row?

Comment: @user1357015, that  could definitely be done. You could add the message instead of `full_text`.

Comment: @Sbista, could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155336/dt-cell-hover-showing-cell-based-sample-sizes-from-hidden-column. This is a questions looking for an extension of your awesome answer here..