# Add tool tip in a datatable in R Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to add tool tip using JS script *attr* function,some how the written script is not giving the desired result (adding tool tip for the 1st column of the datatable).As I am new JS Script so unable to debug the error, can anyone suggest me why the below code is not giving me the correct result. Here is the piece of code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(

DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

),
server = function(input, output) {

output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
  responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
  displayableData<-as.data.frame(responseDataFilter2_home, stringAsFactors = FALSe, row.names = NULL)
},server = TRUE, selection = 'single',callback = JS("table.on('dblclick.dt', 'td', function(nRow, aData){
                                                         var row=table.cell(this).index().row;
                                                        var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]
                                                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);
                                                         Shiny.onInputChange('rows_home',[row, Math.random()]);});
                                                         table.on('click.dt', 'td', function(nRow, aData) {
                                                         var k=table.cell(this).index().row;
                                                        var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]
                                                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);
                                                         if(table.rows('.selected').indexes().toArray()!= '' && table.rows('.selected').indexes().toArray() ==k){
                                                         k=-1;}
                                                         Shiny.onInputChange('rows_up_home',[k, Math.random()]);
                                                         });"),
escape=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE,searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%', targets = c(1)))),rownames=FALSE,colnames="Name")

}
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are exactly trying to display in your tooltip?

Comment: @SBista I have trying to have concatenation of col1 and col2 and display the same as tool tip in col1 by keeping other part of JS Script untouched as there are designed for some other feature.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code with the answer that I gave in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40634033/5894457) so that you get the tooltip without affecting other parts of your JS code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
      responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
      displayableData<-DT::datatable(data = as.data.frame(responseDataFilter2_home, stringAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = NULL),rownames = FALSE,
                                     escape = FALSE, selection = 'single', callback =  JS("table.on('dblclick.dt', 'td', function(nRow, aData){
                                                         var row=table.cell(this).index().row;
                                                        var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]
                                                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);
                                                        Shiny.onInputChange('rows_home',[row, Math.random()]);});
                                                        table.on('click.dt', 'td', function(nRow, aData) {
                                                        var k=table.cell(this).index().row;
                                                        var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]
                                                        $('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);
                                                        if(table.rows('.selected').indexes().toArray()!= '' && table.rows('.selected').indexes().toArray() ==k){
                                                        k=-1;}
                                                        Shiny.onInputChange('rows_up_home',[k, Math.random()]);
                                                        });"),

                                     options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                                       "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                                       "var full_text = aData[0] + ','+ aData[1];",
                                       "$('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
                                       "}"),paging=FALSE,searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                                       columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%', targets = c(1))),colnames="Name") )


    })

    })
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. It helps. Just one more query- As table displayed has 3 cols- 4,3,1. Now,if I need to have tool tip of col 2 & col 5 on col1, what is work around for the same. Actual Table will dispaly col-4,3,1 only but concatenation of tool tip will have 2 & 5. Keeping iris table as an example.

Comment: Since you have extracted the data for columns 4,3 and 1 only, the datatable won't have access to the values of column 2 and 5. To do so I guess the best way would be  to hide unwanted columns while displaying  instead of extracting the columns from `iris` to `responseDataFilter2_home`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. To hide the cols dynamically we can add this code - columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%',                                                visible=FALSE, targets=c(3,4)))

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("table2")

  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$table2<-DT::renderDataTable({
      responseDataFilter2_home<-iris[,c(4,3,1)]
      displayableData<-DT::datatable(responseDataFilter2_home,options = list(rowCallback = JS(
        "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
        "var full_text = aData[1] + ','+ aData[2]",
        "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "}")
      ))#, stringAsFactors = FALSe, row.names = NULL)
    },server = TRUE, selection = 'single', escape=FALSE,options=list(paging=FALSE,searching = FALSE,ordering=FALSE,scrollY = 400,scrollCollapse=TRUE,
                          columnDefs = list(list(width = '800%', targets = c(1)))),rownames=FALSE,colnames="Name")

    }
 )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I try to integrate this with existing JS elements which are part of existing code.Tool tip didn't works. And that is the problem with my original code - Other things works but not the tool tip.any work around that?

Comment: what else do you want to do other than adding the tooltips as they are added with this minimal code?

Comment: Ur code works fine for tool tip but I need to integrate the tool tip with already written JS Script in that I was having the problem. Thanks for ur effort.