# Datatable tooltip from another column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

How do I add a tooltip (or a mouseover popup) to cells of a datatable, that pulls data from another column?

For example if I display first three columns of mtcars in a datable, how do I display a tooltip with hp (horsepower) data of the car name I am currently hovering over with my mouse?

There are [similar questions on how you can display static text as a tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970097/tooltip-or-popover-in-shiny-datatables-for-row-names), but I can't find a way to display data from another column as a toolptip.

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyUI(
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")
  )   
)    

#server.R

library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
  output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(mtcars[, 1:3]))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the tooltip  with hp you can modify your server code as follows:

```
   shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({
      datatable(mtcars[, 1:4], options = list(rowCallback = JS(
        "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
        "var full_text = aData[4]",
        "$('td:eq(0)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "$('td:eq(1)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "$('td:eq(2)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
        "}"),

        columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=c(4)))
      )
      )
    }) 
  })
```

The `JS` code adds the tooltip to first four columns with the value  of hp column.
Here the dataset contains the hp column but we are hiding that column using `columnDefs` parameter.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It does help a ton! Actually, this answers my question perfectly. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @AdamB: With `rownames=FALSE` there are only 4 columns, indexed by 0, 1, 2, 3.