# How to insert a hover over pop up window in R Shiny table?

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, popup, dt

I found an old post, [Add bootstrap tooltip to column header in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35730287/add-bootstrap-tooltip-to-column-header-in-shiny-app), that basically and almost gets at what I need but I'm trying to clean it up. My questions are:

(1) how to remove the annoying pop up what appears when first invoking the below Code, as shown in the next image,

(2) will there be a way to adjust the size of, and otherwise format, the text ("*HELLO*") that appears when hovering over the table column header, and

(3) are there better options now for doing this sort of thing, where you get an editable, formattable pop-window (with user instructions) when you hover over a specific text string in a table?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(12,dataTableOutput('table'))))
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderDataTable(
    iris,
    options = 
      list(
      pageLength = 5,
        initComplete = I("function(settings, json) {alert('Done.');
            $('th').each( function(){this.setAttribute('title','HELLO');});  
            $('th').tooltip();
            }")
      )
    )
    
  tags$head(tags$script("
      $('table th').each(function(){ console.log( $(this).text());
            $(this).attr('data-toggle','tooltip')
            $(this).attr('title','example text')
            $(this).tooltip();
        );
      "))
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Answer to your question about how to remove the box, remove `alert('Done.')`

Comment: Might be worth looking at the `shinyBS` package - see https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/docs/Tooltips_and_Popovers.html

Comment: Agreed, shinyBS is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have an id for the header, you can apply the `shinyBS::bsPopover` function. To have an id, you can use the `container` argument of `DT::datatable`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyBS)

sketch = htmltools::withTags(
  table(
    class = "display",
    thead(
      tr(
        th("Sepal length"),
        th("Sepal width"),
        th("Petal length"),
        th("Petal width"),
        th("Species", id = "header-species")
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable"),
  bsPopover(
    id      = "header-species",
    title   = "Species",
    content = "This is the species column"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, container = sketch)    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]